# Hide div if geolocation IP is from a particular country

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

For example, I'm trying to hide the 'ohi_widget' div if people view our website ([www.1907water.com](https://www.1907water.com)) from New Zealand.

Is this possible, and if so, what code is required?

Thanks

I tried Google search, online chat, and Stack Overflow search. I tried one 'solution' but it didn't work on our site, probably because I had to customise it and I do not understand javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ipapi.co](https://ipapi.co/):

```js
fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Check if the country is New Zealand and hide div
    if (data.country === 'NZ') {
      document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching IP data:', error);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hide Div for NZ IPs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv">
    This div will be hidden if your IP suggests you are in New Zealand.
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Validated using my personal US IP and a Surfshark VPN NZ IP.*

Comment: Thanks, I will try that now. Do I wrap that in <script></script> tags?

Comment: That's me. I don't understand Javascript hence my questions. I've put this in <script> tags in the header. It's not working at this stage.

Comment: The script relies on the DOM element (`myDiv`) being available when it runs. If you place the script in the `<head>` without waiting for the DOM to be fully loaded, it won't work as expected. You have two options:

1. Place the script just before the closing `</body>` tag.
2. If you want it in the `<head>`, use an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded`:

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // Your fetch code here
});`

Either way ensures that the DOM element you're trying to manipulate is available when your script runs.